# Ruby csv upload does not show records in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a functional ruby app which I created by following a baserails tutorial with little or no fus, I tried to upload multiple records into the database by following this [tutorial](https://deepakrip007.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/import-csv-file-into-the-database-in-rails-application/comment-page-1/#comment-579). 
It seemed pretty straight forward and figured I could have it up in minutes.

The problem is when I upload the csv file , I get a notification that my upload was successful, Firstly, only one record gets created, secondly the created record is empty.

I have searched and searched, tried other tutorials and end up having the same issue... I am basically at wits end. Please see snippets of my code below:

**hospital.rb**

```
class Hospital < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  searchkick

  has_many :reviews

  #validates :name, :address, :phone, :image, presence: true
  #validates :website, format: { with: /\Ahttps?:\/\/.*\z/,
  #message: "must start with http:// or https://" }
  #validates :phone, numericality: {
  #only_integer: true,
  #message: "must be land line(7 digits) or Gsm(11 digits)"
  #}
end
```

**hospital_controller.rb**

```
class HospitalsController < ApplicationController

  ...

    def import
      Hospital.import(params[:file])
    end

  ...

    def create

      @hospital = Hospital.new(hospital_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @hospital.save
          format.html { redirect_to @hospital, notice: 'Hospital was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hospital }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @hospital.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

    end

  private

    def hospital_params
      params.require(:hospital).permit(:name, :address, :city_town, :state, :phone, :website, :safe_care, :jci, :cohsasa, :best_known_4, :image )
    end

end
```

Output on Rails server

```
 Started POST "/hospitals" for ::1 at 2017-06-22 12:58:09 +0100
 Processing by HospitalsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 


 "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==", 
  "hospital"=>{"name"=>"", 
 "address"=>"", "city_town"=>"", "state"=>"", "phone"=>"", "website"=>"", 
 "safe_care"=>"", "jci"=>"", "cohsasa"=>"", "best_known_4"=>""}, "file"=>#
 <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe064b78918 @tempfile=#


 <Tempfile:/var/folders/xh/hv6bwdzs3cx4ws9x42n3gsn00000gn/
 T/RackMultipart20170622-80750-147ctbc.csv>, @original_filename="Test.csv", 
 @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
 name=\"file\"; filename=\"Test.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">, 
 "commit"=>"Import CSV"}
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? 
 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  commit transaction
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "hospitals" ("name", "address", "phone", "website", 
"created_at", "updated_at", "city_town", "state", "jci", "cohsasa", 
"best_known_4", "safe_care") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
[["name", ""], ["address", ""], ["phone", ""], ["website", ""], ["created_at", 
2017-06-22 11:58:09 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-22 11:58:09 UTC], 
["city_town", ""], ["state", ""], ["jci", ""], ["cohsasa", ""], 
["best_known_4", ""], ["safe_care", ""]]
(0.8ms)  commit transaction
Hospital Store (170.8ms)  {"id":53}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/hospitals/53
Completed 302 Found in 188ms (Searchkick: 170.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is behaving exactly how you have written it to behave:

> *Firstly, only one record gets created*...

Yep. Because you never call:

```
Hospital.import(params[:file])
```

It's in your `import` action, but you never call it from your `create` action. When the tutorial says:

> Step:3
>
> Add the block in your controller

It doesn't mean 'any old place you like and it will magically be called'. You have to actually *call* the logic. But, you don't. So your application does nothing with the CSV file. Which is exactly what you've told it to do with the CSV file.

(Also, your `Hospital` class doesn't have an import class method. So, when you do finally get around to calling it, it'll throw an error.)

> *Secondly the created record is empty...*

Yep again. Just as you wrote it to do.

As you can see in your console, your hospital params are empty:

```
Started POST "/hospitals" for ::1 at 2017-06-22 12:58:09 +0100
Processing by HospitalsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
  "hospital"=>{
    "name"=>"", 
    "address"=>"", 
    "city_town"=>"", 
    "state"=>"", 
    "phone"=>"", 
    "website"=>"", 
    "safe_care"=>"", 
    "jci"=>"", 
    "cohsasa"=>"", 
    "best_known_4"=>""
  },
  "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe064b78918 @tempfile=#
```

So, when you do:

```
  @hospital = Hospital.new(hospital_params)
```

Then:

```
  if @hospital.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
```

Well, you just told your application to create a blank record and it merrily complies (in particular because you've removed all your validations).

So... Write Hospital.import method (see step 4 of the tutorial) something like this:

```
  class Hospital < ApplicationRecord

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    searchkick

    has_many :reviews

    #validates :name, :address, :phone, :image, presence: true
    #validates :website, format: { with: /\Ahttps?:\/\/.*\z/,
    #message: "must start with http:// or https://" }
    #validates :phone, numericality: {
    #only_integer: true,
    #message: "must be land line(7 digits) or Gsm(11 digits)"
    #}

    def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Hospital.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end

  end
```

Call it in your controller, something like:

```
    def create

      import if params[:file] # <= this here is the call to your import method

      @hospital = Hospital.new(hospital_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @hospital.save
          format.html { redirect_to @hospital, notice: 'Hospital was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hospital }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @hospital.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

    end
```

Add your validations back in. And you'll be a lot closer to on your way.

Comment: Thank you for this... Maybe i forgot to add, i am a pure IT infrastructure Enginner trying to learn new skills so a lot of your terms though sound familiar, i am unsure as to how to proceed.                                                   How do i Write Hospital.import method and call it in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in model to import csv ini db and call it in controller:

```
def self.import(file)
      spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
      header = spreadsheet.row(2)
      (3..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = spreadsheet.row(i) #Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        f1= from = row[0]
        f2 = row[1]
        f3 = row[2]


        ModelName.create({f1: f1, ... })
      end
end
```

Comment: Hello Puneet18, i just did and it is the same situation.. No records in the database.

Comment: where you upload the csv?

Comment: open link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm and follow steps for file uploading

Comment: Hi, I am not looking to upload a document, i want to add the contents of the csv file to my database.

Comment: you didnt add any code to extract csv and add data in db

Comment: Thanks @puneet18 it's been sorted now.